# Web Scraping on multiple pages with RSelenium and select emails with regular expression

Tags: r, rselenium

I would like to collect email addresses clicking each name from this website https://ki.se/en/research/professors-at-ki I created the following loop. For some reason some email are not collected, and the code is very slow...
Do you have a better code idea?
Thank you very much in advance

```
library(RSelenium)

#use Rselenium to dowload emails
rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4545L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("https://ki.se/en/research/professors-at-ki")


database<-data.frame(NA, nrow = length(name), ncol = 3)

for(i in 1:length(name)){
  #first website
  remDr$navigate("https://ki.se/en/research/professors-at-ki")
  elems <- remDr$findElements(using = 'xpath', "//strong")   #all elements to be selected
  elem <- elems[[i]] #do search and click on each one
  class(elem)
 people<- elem$getElementText()
  elem$clickElement()
  page <- remDr$getPageSource()
  #stringplit
  p<-str_split(as.character(page), "\n")
  a<-grep("@", p[[1]])

  if(length(a)>0){
    email<-p[[1]][a[2]]
    email<-gsub(" ", "", email)        
    database[i,1]<-people
    database[i,2]<-email
    database[i,3]<-"Karolinska Institute"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RSelenium` is usually not the fastest approach as it requires the browser to load the page. There are cases, when `RSelenium` is the only option, but in this case, you can achieve what you need using `rvest` library, which should be faster. As for the errors you receive, there are two professors, for which the links provided do not seem to be working, thus the errors you receive.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

# getting links to professors microsites as part of the KI main website
r <- read_html("https://ki.se/en/research/professors-at-ki")

people_links <- r %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_attrs() %>%
  as.character() %>%
  str_subset("https://staff.ki.se/people/")

# accessing the obtained links, getting the e-mails
df <- tibble(people_links) %>%
  # filtering out these links as they do not seem to be accessible
  filter( !(people_links %in% c("https://staff.ki.se/people/gungra", "https://staff.ki.se/people/evryla")) ) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    mail = read_html(people_links) %>%
      html_nodes("a") %>%
      html_attrs() %>%
      as.character() %>%
      str_subset("mailto:") %>%
      str_remove("mailto:")
  )
```

Comment: @QHarr I have added some additional explanation. OP originally asked for coding ideas so I tried to provided one. You are right that a little explanation may help though. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: You are right that I missed a lot of people, but when I try to access e.g. https://ki.se/en/node/10657, there seem to be no e-mail addresses on that page. But you are right that if you follow the link there, there are other e-mails.

Comment: Agree. I did not delete the answer as it may provide some ideas to OP.

Comment: +1 It does. You might be able to shorten your first bit by just using `people_links <- r %>% html_nodes('strong [href*=people]') %>% html_attrs('href')` ?

Comment: I tried to incorporate your suggestion, but it only returns 111 results. The original one returned 194.

Comment: Just remove the strong `people_links <- r %>% html_nodes('href*=people]') %>% html_attrs('href')`  then you get 194